# Copy/Paste not working in Java application

Tags: java, notepad++, clipboard, lotus-notes

I'm using Microsoft Internet Explorer with a java plug-in for my work email (IBM Lotus Notes) while on holiday. When I log into my work email, I get the following warning:

```
 WARNING: The following resource is signed with a weak signature algorithm MD5withRSA and is treated as unsigned
```

I've added my work email address into the Control Panel > Java > Security > Exception Site List.

When I choose to send a new email, I can select text within the browser and paste to an external application (like Notepad++). The reverse (from Notepad++ to the Browser) also works fine.

However, on replying to an email, a big "Java" symbol appears and loads a more complex form and in this form Copy/Paste does not work. Curiously, I can copy/paste WITHIN the Java application. Note that the email works fine...just not the copy/paste.

I've read this is about Java security which has disabled access to the system clipboard. After following the advise in this [this external article](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/resources/InstructionsCopyPaste) and [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513740/copy-paste-not-working-in-a-signed-applet), it is not working for me. I've added the permission to the .java.policy file and copied the file to the HOME path. I've closed and re-opened the browser and then restarted the whole machine. Still not working.

OS: Windows 8.1
Java: build 1.8.0_131-b11

Answer (score 1):

I think that strictly speaking, it's not a Java plugin that you're talking about here.

I think it's the IBM Lotus Notes browsr plugin, which is first and foremost a set of native code DLLs that implement the Notes client framework and features running inside your browser. The Notes plugin is installed in C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\Notes and uses a data directory c:\users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\IBM\Notes\Data.  Where Java enters into is that this plugin includes its own private JVM. which is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\jvm - and it is a different version from the 1.8 that you have installed on your computer. (AFAIK, IBM does't support version 1.8 in the Notes client piugin). This version of Java is installed in order to provide a consistent Java version and environment to support Java-applets that implement features of the Notes mail application (and other Notes applications). It is the policy file for this version of the JVM that I think you need to work with in order to solve this problem.

Comment: This sounds about right, but I have no `IBM` folder anywhere on my computer. I log into my work email via Internet Explorer (which is NPAPI enabled, while Chrome is not). As far as I can tell the Java JAR applet is hosted by my work (`http://www.MY-COMPANY.biz/domjava/actionbar.jar`). This is from my personal laptop, I've never taken it into work to have anything work-related installed.

Comment: You said that you were using the "java plugin". That term has a very specific meaning in both the Notes and browser worlds - and implies that an actual download and install of Notes client code is done by your browser. Based on your comment, that's not what's going on. Instead, you are using one of the various IBM Domino webmail implementations that uses Java applets to implement some of the functionality.

Comment: Your problem is likely being caused by one of two things. Either your company is simply running a very old version of Domino that only supports an obsolete webmail template that is no longer supported and has some forward compatibility issues with modern browsers and JVMs, or your system does support IBM's modern webmail (it has gone by several different names: "iNotes" or "Domino Web Access") but your system administrator has not upgraded your mail database to use it.

Comment: It is likely that the webmail template or mail database is rather old. I will check with my system administrator to confirm. Thanks for the comment.